# Unable to populate dynamic data in dialog using javscript

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am working on hybrid application using Angularjs and Angular 8.I am trying to populate data inside the dialog which contains paragraphs,inputs,textarea and label. When I click the icon to open the dialog, the dialog gets opened but it is not showing the data however when i change d[image]ialog to div it shows. I am trying it for so long but nothing works. Any idea please ?

```
<dialog id="p-modal">
    <p>{{glPlmAsmt.data.summary}}</p>
    <button>Ok</button>
</dialog>
```

I have data in **glPlmAsmt.data.summary** which is fetched from server but it is not showing in dialog but shows in div